# Using PySimpleGUI to divide the window in columns gives an error

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am tring to construct a GUi that would display two columns:
one column would have all the input fields and listboxes, the second column would display some data from `pandas dataframe`.

I thought it would be a good idea to do this using `Frames`, but I am running into an error when trying to create a `Frame`:

```
layout = [sg.Frame('Input data',[[
          sg.Text('Input:'),      
          sg.Input(do_not_clear=False),      
          sg.Button('Read'), sg.Exit(),
          sg.Text('Alternatives:'),
          sg.Listbox(values=('alternatives...', ''), size=(30, 2), key='_LISTBOX_')]])]
```

Result:

> TypeError: AddRow() argument after * must be an iterable, not Frame

How to fix this?

I am thinking if it is possible to define columns first, using `Frame`, and then putting the columns into the definition of `layout`?

Comment: which line gives error message? Always show it in question (not in comment)

Comment: you could create minimal working example with your problem so we could run it and search solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `[[ ]]`

```
layout = [[

]]
```

External `[ ]` means all data, internal `[ ]` means first row - even if you need only one row.

---

Working example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[
    sg.Frame('Input data',[[
          sg.Text('Input:'),      
          sg.Input(do_not_clear=False),      
          sg.Button('Read'), sg.Exit(),
          sg.Text('Alternatives:'),
          sg.Listbox(values=('alternatives...', ''), size=(30, 2), key='_LISTBOX_')
    ]])
]]

window = sg.Window('App', layout)
event, values = window.Read()
window.Close()
```

Comment: Spot on correct! All layouts in PySimpleGUI are a "list of lists of elements".  That's true for all of the "Container Elements" including Column, Frame, etc.  They all take that same [ [   ] ]   format.

Comment: @MikeyB it almost the same - I called it "list of rows of elements" :)

Comment: Correct you are.  List of rows of Elements is exactly what they are.